# any ideas to solve kigg trust level with shared hosting problem?

Tags: asp.net, security, hosting

I tried to setup KIGG on my server, but always had a permission problem and i knew that its because the trust level, and  godaddy always says that http://help.godaddy.com/article/1039

if someone faced the same problem before please advice.
Note: I can't currently move to another hosting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to handle it is to re-compile the application in Medium Trust. This assumes that KIGG can run in medium trust.

[More Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998341.aspx)

[How To: Use Code Access Security in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998326.aspx)